# Create div element using Aloha editor without review/source mode in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I can't seem to find how a content author can create a div element when editing content using Aloha editor without going through the review/source tab. How can authors with no HTML knowledge create div elements in content? If this is not available by default how can this be customised?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the Aloha editor would be used to create basic HTML content only.  Inserting DIV tags sounds like you are using the editor to control layout - this is not ideal as it is too easy for editors to get into a mess with it.  The layout of your page should be set in the ASPX / ASCX templates, into which you add basic content.

However it is possible to [customise the editor](https://developer.ektron.com/Experts/Andrew-Eddy/Getting-to-know-Aloha/) by adding new buttons.